# Selecting a non-standard event object from fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I created a new data line for my object inside fullcalendar called "type: 'p'" that stands for project and looks something like this:

```
{
    id: '201311',
    title: 'Event1',
    start: '2014-01-22',
    end: '2014-01-22',
    allDay: true,
},

{
    id: '201315',
    title: 'Project1',
    start: '2014-01-22',
    end: '2014-01-22',
    allDay: true,
    type: 'p'
}
```

When I try to modify the event with type:'p' to change color nothing changes, here's my code:

```
// Color the projects to blue or green
$(element).data('eventType', event.type);
$('div.fc-event-inner').each(function(){
    if (event.type == $(this).data('eventType', 'p')){
        $('div.fc-event-inner').css("background", "#3366cc");
    }else{
        $('div.fc-event-inner').css("background", "#009933");
    }
});
```

Right now everything gets colored to green rather than 'p' to blue and others to green.
Here's a link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jcarlomorales/Hb3g3/1/

Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.data('eventType', event.type);
    element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background",event.type == 'p'? "#3366cc":"#009933");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5DCnZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `className` event property? http://jsfiddle.net/5DCnZ/5/